# In hook_menu `page callback` function is executing twice

Tags: 6, routes

In this menu My `page callback` function is calling two times. In `get_mydata` function a `fetchthedata` function is calling which takes long time to run. It was perfectly fine earlier. But now it is running twice. I don't know why? If I comment the `fetchthedata` then it only entry the watchdog single time.

My code is :

```
function custom_data_menu() { 
    $items['mymenu'] = array(
        'title' => 'My Title',
        'description' => 'My Desc',
        'page callback' => 'get_mydata',
        'access arguments' => array('permission for custommenu'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function get_mydata() {
      watchdog('Start', 'Start');
      $query = db_query("myquery with limit 1");
      while($field = db_fetch_array($query)) {
             watchdog('Runsfor', 'Start for a user');
             fetchthedata($arg1, $arg2);
             watchdog('Runsfor', 'Ends for a user');
        }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that function is not called from another place? Page callbacks are called once for every time its menu path is accessed.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yeah I changed the menu path and function name both. But still issue remaining. :(

Comment: @kiamlaluno Now its running multiple times. :(

Comment: Pass to `watchdog()` the value returned from `time()`, and see the difference between those values. I can assure you, a page callback is only called once each time its page URL is accessed. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you what is wrong in your case, as I don't have enough information.

Comment: @SumitMadan Add this code in `get_mydata()` `$trace  = debug_backtrace();
 array_shift($trace);watchdog('Debug',$trace[0]['function']);` This will log all functions that call `get_mydata()`. It will help you to debug. may be someother function is also calling this.

Comment: @2-Stroker If I changed the name of function and menu both how can other function call it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Can curl request be a reason for this?

Comment: I manage it by setting a variable. But I didn't found any reason yet. I think May be `Curl` request.

Comment: were you able to solve this ? i'm having the same problem

Comment: Check if any curl request executing on the same page. I forgot what was the reason but seems it was related to curl request.